# How do I make a program that reverse user input of integers in Java?

Tags: java, reverse

Well, I have made this simple start, but I could not think of a way to reverse user input of integers.

My start:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

    Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("> ");
    String input = console.nextLine();
    while (! input.equals("quit")){ 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("> ");
        input = console.next();
    }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: Invalid Input");
    }
    System.out.println("Bye!"); 


}
```

So, I want user input such as 10 15 40 100 3400 to become 3400 100 40 15 10. I know that is cal use array.tostring someplace, but I do not know where and how.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: This is basically just asking us to write your program for you.

Comment: Do you want to implement the reversing or use a library method?

Comment: Since you don't know how many integers you are going to receive you may want to use an arraylist (dynamic array variable length) of integers. Just fill the arraylist with integers then create another for loop to loop through the arraylist in reverse order and print each integer.

Comment: A each element to some kind of List/array and use a bubble sort to sort it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store each input in a `List<String>` and iterate in reverse order on your array for the output.

This is a transformed version of your initial `main()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("> ");
        String input = console.nextLine();
        out.add(input);

        while (!input.equals("quit")){ 
            input = console.next();
            out.add(input);
        }
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error: Invalid Input");
        }

        for(int i = out.size() - 1; i >=0; i--){
            System.out.println(out.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println("Bye!"); 
}
```

Comment: How would I get it to work? What do I need to import? I could not get this code running.

Comment: You will have to import java.util.ArrayList, java.util.List and java.util.Scanner.

Comment: Why would I need to import both java.util.list and arraylist?

Comment: Because of this line List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: O, I got it know. Thanks

Comment: I selected it. It worked, and now I understand it, too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ...

```
String myNum = "10 15 40 100 3400";
String[] numbers = myNum.split(" ");
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(numbers);
Collections.reverse(myList); // myList will has 3400 100 40 15 10
```

Comment: `100 200` becomes `002 001`

Answer (score 1):

Add the `inputs` to a `ArrayList` then use reverse command.

```
ArrayList<int> aList = new ArrayList<int>();
```

To add

```
aList.add(input);
```

To reverse

```
Collections.reverse(aList);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Integer[] ints = {10, 20, 5, 55}; // Get the input from user and for an Integer array
        List<Integer> integers= Arrays.asList(ints);
        Collections.reverse(integers);
        System.out.println(integers);

    }
```

Output:

```
[55, 5, 20, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, I'm going to make some assumptions:

a) You know all inputs will be integers
b) You don't need to *do* anything with the integers, just print them (ie: arithmetic)
c) You only want to reverse the order, not any other kind of orders
d) Your integers are separated by spaces always

**If assumption B is correct**

Since you are reading the inputs in as a string, and since your example uses space separated values, you then need to

1) Separate the inputs and
2) Print them individually (in reverse order)

So to do the first point, you can use a string utility that separates a string based on a character. [How to split a string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)). If you aren't familiar with arrays, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) is reference.

It would look something like.

```
String input = console.nextLine();
String[] inputArray = input.split(" ");
```

At this point, inputArray would look like `{"10", "15", "40", "100", "3400"}`.

Now you just need a way to display each in reverse order. An easy way to do this would be with a [for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) because you can direct it and you know how many times it will execute. Since you want to print in reverse order, you will start at the end and work to the beginning. Like this:

```
for (int i = inputArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

Then simply print out the element of the array, making your loop look thus:

```
for (int i = inputArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(inputArray[i]);
}
```

**If assuption B is not correct**

This would mean you need you use the integers in some way. This will simply add one step to the previous process (i.e. "If assumption B is correct") where you convert ("parse") the string into an integer. So starting with the code from the previous section:

```
String input = console.nextLine();
String[] inputArray = input.split(" ");

for (int i = inputArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(inputArray[i]);
}
```

We first want to create a structure to hold the integers, then we want to put each string into the integer array. We do this by using the [`static Integer.valueOf(String input)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) method.

```
String input = console.nextLine();
    String[] inputArray = input.split(" ");

    // Array to hold integer values
    int[] inputIntArray = new int[inputArray.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < inputIntArray.length; i++) {
        inputIntArray[i] = Integer.valueOf(inputArray[i]);
    }

    for (int i = inputIntArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        // Do whatever operations you want here

        System.out.println(inputIntArray[i]);
    }
```

Then you should be good.

Comment: Very detailed. I was not thinking about using arrays, but now I see that using it is necessary.

Comment: "Necessary" is not quite right. They are appropriate for this simple example, but there are other implementations that work. Think more about the underlying steps involved in this answer, less about the data structures, so as not to tunnel vision on one solution. A list or a stack could very easily solve this problem. Glad I could help, though.

Comment: Oh, so arraylist is very different than array. I see. Need to read up a little more.

Comment: They are different, yes. But, they can be used the same with minimal usage differences. For example, with arrays you access a member with someArray[index] whereas with an ArrayList (and any List, for that matter) you will do someList.get(index). The biggest difference when starting is that ArrayLists have dynamic size, so you can keep adding, whereas arrays have a fixes size. So, if your array is full and you need to add one, you need to create a new array, but with a list you would just someList.add(newElement).